# Androidplot: Set padding/margin to (perfectly) accommodate axis labels

Tags: androidplot

In an androidplot XYPlot, the tick labels on the Y axis get clipped if you have large values (many digits) and/or a large font size. This (and similar issues on the X axis) has been discussed before in these questions:

- [Range field in Android Plot (0.6.1.) is not showing the entire number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964945/range-field-in-android-plot-0-6-1-is-not-showing-the-entire-number)
- [Androidplot - X-Axis labels cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780552/androidplot-x-axis-labels-cut-off)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidplot/b0zLJl9Bx-0
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidplot/w4EK4B_W-74

The answer is always to add more padding and/or margin in order to have enough space for the labels.

**My question is**: How can I set the padding/margin to have **just the right amount** of space?

Simply hardcoding the left margin to some value is a suboptimal solution. Let's assume I want to plot some data and I don't know in advance if the Y values will be in the range [0,9] or in the range [10000,20000]. How can I set the padding/margin to avoid both clipping and unnecessary empty space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I could find was this:

```
int digits = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(absmax)) + 1;
float leftpad = digits * fontsize/2;
myplot.getGraphWidget().setPaddingLeft(leftpad);
```

Where absmax is the greatest absolute value in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this which I think will do the trick.  My setup is more complex as I overlay multiple plots on top of each other to get a multi range affect.

```
left_pad = mTripPlot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelWidth() - 1;
mTripPlot.getGraphWidget().setPadding(left_pad, top_pad, right_pad, bottom_pad);
```

Comment: For me, `getRangeLabelWidth()` always returns 41.0, irrespective of the values on the Y axis and of the font size I set using `getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setTextSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs it, here is how I set dynamic padding for the range labels with the current version of AndroidPlot (1.5.7)

```
 String largestString = getLargestLabelOnRange();
 float rangeLabelPadding = largestString.length() * 9;
 plot.getGraph().setPaddingLeft(rangeLabelPadding);
```